# Why can't I use Pandas in Jupyter even with "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image: Issue With Jupyter]

Hey there. So I'm trying to learn Python for data manipulation. Obviously pandas is needed. I am using Windows 10 and have installed Jupyter through the console. I have had no problem getting into the jupyter notebook on my localhost and running basic commands like print. However, I cannot use pandas for some reason. Any guidance of where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3 in your notebook? It could be that you are installing using pip (often python2) but the notebook is running python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a new kernel? If so, `!pip` runs pip using the system environment, not the kernel environment. Delete the `!` at the beginning.